# Kill all running JavaScript functions on click

Tags: javascript, function

This is an extension of my previous question, mainly out of curiosity: [Kill all running JavaScript functions with Timeouts on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144668/kill-all-running-javascript-functions-with-timeouts-on-click)

I have a webpage with 3 buttons and a "result" section:

```html
<button id="b1" onclick="f1()">1st button</button>
<button id="b2" onclick="f2()">2nd button</button>
<button id="b3" onclick="f3()">3rd button</button>
<p id="result">"Here will be the result!"</p>
```

Here are the snippets for the JavaScript functions. I also utilized web worker:

```js
// The functions are similar, but the outputs are different

var worker;

function calcF1() {
    var answer;
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) {
        // Do some complicated calculations
    }
    postMessage(answer);
}

function f1() {
    // TODO: Kill other running instances of all functions

    // Calling worker
    var cf1 = calcF1.toString();
    var code = cf1.substring(cf1.indexOf('{')+1, cf1.lastIndexOf('}'));
    var blob = new Blob([code], {type: 'application/javascript'});
    worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));

    worker.onmessage = message => {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "1st function";
    };
}

function calcF2() {
    var answer;
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) {
        // Do some complicated calculations
    }
    postMessage(answer);
}

function f2() {
    // TODO: Kill other running instances of all functions

    // Calling worker
    var cf2 = calcF2.toString();
    var code = cf2.substring(cf2.indexOf('{')+1, cf2.lastIndexOf('}'));
    var blob = new Blob([code], {type: 'application/javascript'});
    worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));

    worker.onmessage = message => {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "2nd function";
    };
}

function calcF3() {
    var answer;
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) {
        // Do some complicated calculations
    }
    postMessage(answer);
}

function f3() {
    // TODO: Kill other running instances of all functions

    // Calling worker
    var cf3 = calcF3.toString();
    var code = cf3.substring(cf3.indexOf('{')+1, cf3.lastIndexOf('}'));
    var blob = new Blob([code], {type: 'application/javascript'});
    worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));

    worker.onmessage = message => {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "3rd function";
    };
}
```

However, if the user clicks `b1` and then immediately click `b2`, the worker by `f1` will not terminate and keep running. If worker from `f1` finishes before that from `f2` does, then `result` will show `1st function` and then replaced by `2nd function`. There's also a possibility that the worker by `f2` finishes first, in which case `result` would show `2nd function` and then be replaced by `1st function`.

What I want is to implement, at the start of each function, a statement that kills/ignores/bypasses all functions and/or all web workers that are currently running so that the final output would always be the one associated with the last button the user pressed. How can it be best implemented?

**EDIT:** Thanks for pointing out the web worker. My original implementations involved web workers but I forgot to mention. The question has been updated.

Comment: You cannot stop a for loop from other function since for loop is synchronized. You cannot even start f2 while f1 is running. Note that Javascript is running only in one thread unless you use web workers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kill all running JavaScript functions with Timeouts on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144668/kill-all-running-javascript-functions-with-timeouts-on-click)

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Comment: That was not a duplicate. For that question I asked for how to kill functions with `setTimeout()`, which seem to be easier to kill. @RuChernChong

Comment: Yes I was actually using one. I've updated the question to reflect that. @PatrickRoberts

Comment: I've modified the question so that it involves worker. I've actually used workers during my testing but forgot to include them here. It does seem that there's no parallelism when workers aren't used (as the browser would just freeze onclick). Greatest thanks for pointing out. @momocow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split up the functions such that they only run for a moderate period of time before stopping and pushing the next run onto the end of the stack with `setTimeout`, so that other functions have a chance to run. At the beginning of each `f1`, `f2`, and `f3`, check to see that they have the unique reference to the key of the current running function, and return if they don't.

In the following snippet, an ongoing `f1` function is getting overridden by a more recent call of `f2`:

```js
let runningFunctionKey;
function f1(key, start = 0) {
  if (!key) {
    runningFunctionKey = {}; // some unique reference
    key = runningFunctionKey;
  } else if (key !== runningFunctionKey) return;
  const until = start + 1e7;
  while (start < until) {
    if (start === 1e9) {
      console.log('f1 done');
      return;
    }
    start++;
  }
  console.log('f1 setting timeout');
  setTimeout(f1, 0, key, start);
}
function f2(key, start = 0) {
  if (!key) {
    runningFunctionKey = {}; // some unique reference
    key = runningFunctionKey;
  } else if (key !== runningFunctionKey) return;
  const until = start + 1e7;
  while (start < until) {
    if (start === 1e9) {
      console.log('f2 done');
      return;
    }
    start++;
  }
  console.log('f2 setting timeout');
  setTimeout(f2, 0, key, start);
}
f1();
setTimeout(f2, 500);
```

Comment: `Symbol()` would probably be a better candidate for a lightweight unique key to use, but I think that [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) would be the way to go here.

Comment: Nice answer! It does seem a little bit not efficient when you have to check at regular intervals, but definitely, this would work!

Comment: @Mushinako If the re-checking frequency is an issue, feel free to increase the execution duration (eg 1e8 rather than the current `until = start + 1e7`), though given this implementation, more frequent re-checking will make for a quicker response to user action.